# Java remove duplicated entry from IHTTPStreamersession for common IP Address

Tags: java, arrays

How do I remove the duplicated entry from this code, where a duplicate entry would be a session that has the same IP address as other sessions?

```
Iterator<IHTTPStreamerSession> iterHttp = httpSessions.iterator();
while(iterHttp.hasNext())
{
    IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession = iterHttp.next();
    if (httpSession == null)
        continue;

    ret.append("<HTTPSession>");
    ret.append("<IpAddress>"+httpSession.getIpAddress()+"</IpAddress>");
    ret.append("<TimeRunning>"+httpSession.getTimeRunningSeconds()+"</TimeRunning>");

    ret.append("</HTTPSession>");
}
```

I need to generate only 1  entry for each `<IpAddress>`

Comment: I don't see how this makes sense. You are iterating over all session and generating an `<HttpSession>` block per session. In that block, you are extracting the unique IP address for that session. Why would you want to set the same IP address for all HttpSessions?

Comment: No, this code is generating more than 1 HTTPSession entry with same IP address and I need to filter this and show only 1 HTTPSession per IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Set check if an IP addresses matches a previously added entry. Something like this:

```
Set<String> ips = new HashSet();
Iterator<IHTTPStreamerSession> iterHttp = httpSessions.iterator();

while(iterHttp.hasNext()){
    IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession = iterHttp.next();
    if (httpSession == null)
        continue;

    String ip = httpSession.getIpAddress();
    if(!ips.contains(ip)){
        ret.append("<HTTPSession>");
        ret.append("<IpAddress>"+ ip +"</IpAddress>");
        ret.append("<TimeRunning>"+httpSession.getTimeRunningSeconds()+"</TimeRunning>");
        ret.append("</HTTPSession>");

        ips.add(ip);
   }
}
```